# Jquery Ajax call got json result 'undefined'

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I want to get json result using Jquery. Now I always got 'undefined' result. I can get the json print out using

```
alert(data);
```

But always return 'undefined' using

```
alert(data.first_name);
```

Jquery client-side code

```
$.post(
    "/modules/services/userlogincheck_new.php",
    {
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        action : "checkpassword",
        email : email,
        password : password
    },
    function(data) {
        alert(data.first_name);
    }
);
```

PHP server-side

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "checkpassword") {
    $query = "select * from users where email='" . $email . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $forumdbcon) or die('Error, insert query failed');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (($row['password'] == md5($password))) {
            $arr = array("response" => 1, "first_name" => $row['first_name'], "last_name" => $row['last_name'], "address" => $row['address1']);
            echo json_encode($arr);
        } else {
            $arr = array("response" => 2);
            echo json_encode($arr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't edit questions' original content to reflect suggestions - it confuses people reading answers that were based on what you originally had.

Comment: since there is an else inside the php code and in that else you are not setting the first_name, are you sure it is going in the if and not in the else?

Comment: What does `alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` output?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! I'll not edit original content anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.post("/modules/services/userlogincheck_new.php", {
   action : "checkpassword",
   email : email,
   password : password
}, function(data) {
   alert(data.first_name);
},'json');
```

Comment: actually $.post is a shortcut method of $.ajax. and if you want data to be returned in your expected format other than html (which is default) then you need to specify it like 'json'. if can also use 'html' if you intended to get data in html format.

Comment: @Sophia: Take a look at the docs for [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).  The 2nd parameter is the data to send to PHP, and the 4th parameter is the `dataType`.  So your `dataType: 'jsonp'` is just sending `$_POST['dataType']` to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The response sent from the server is JSON not JSONP.  Change dataType to JSON.

Comment: The OP's using `$.post`, not `$.ajax`, it needs to be `,'json')`, not `dataType: json`.

Comment: You're right, the syntax is wrong.  Regardless, the dataType param for the $.post function needs to be set to json.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `jsonp` since this is on the server.  <strike>Try changing `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`.</strike>

You're using [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), so you're just sending the `dataType` to PHP, which doesn't do anyting, you need to tell `$.post` to use JSON.

```
$.post("/modules/services/userlogincheck_new.php", {
  action : "checkpassword",
  email : email,
  password : password
}, function(data) {
  alert(data.first_name);
}, 'json;);
```

Comment: @Sophia: I misread your original code, try my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Off topic": **Your code <strike>is</strike> might be highly vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)**. If I transmitted `';DROP TABLE users; --` as my email address, you woud be in trouble.

On topic:

```
$.post(
    "/modules/services/userlogincheck_new.php",
    {
        action : "checkpassword",
        email : email,
        password : password
    },
    function(data) {
        alert(data.first_name);
    },
    'json'
);
```

`$.post()` needs the data-type to be set explicitely.

Comment: It _may_ be vulnerable to SQL injection.  The OP doesn't show where they set `$email`.  I assume they're doing `$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);`.

Comment: Updated "is" to "might be" :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `jsonp`, so you need to wrap your output in a function call, per the parameter given by the automatically created `jsonp` parameter.

```
echo $_GET['jsonp'] . '(' . json_encode($arr) . ');';
```

Alternatively, just use plain JSON instead.

Comment: jQuery usually sends the `callback` parameter via `$_GET`.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, this isn't _actually_ JSONP.  The OP's using `$.post` (not `$.ajax`), so `dataType` is just being sent to PHP as a `$_POST` variable (which doesn't do anything).